# How to verify if retrieved link redirect correctly?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I would like to check if the element I clicked on redirect me to the url it supposed to be. Let say we have a "href" element, before clicking on it, we gather the href attribute value from it, and then, after clicking and redirection we are veryfiying whreter the retirved href attribute value is equal current url page. I have made such code and not sure if it meet expecations:

```
clickOnLinkAndRedirect() {
     PageSelectors.testSelector().click().invoke('attr', 'href').then(href => {
     let URL = href
     cy.url().should('eq', URL)
     })
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add the HTML element of the href tag?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the redirection URL opens in the same tab, you can do like this:

```js
PageSelectors.testSelector()
  .invoke('attr', 'href')
  .then((url) => {
    PageSelectors.testSelector().click()
    cy.url().should('eq', url)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your app redirects the user, it might be better to check the new url contains the pathname you expect out of the redirect.

```js
clickOnLinkAndRedirect() {
     PageSelectors.testSelector().click()
     cy.location('pathname').should('include','/expected/path')
```